# Node Websockets Broadcast not working

Tags: node.js, websocket

Currently having an issue with "Broadcast" not seeming to function properly with a super simple websocket setup I started in Node. This is my first time working with websockets so I may be missing something pretty apparent, but after looking online for a while I wasn't able to find a resolution.

Basically I am just trying to have the ability to push some json out to all currently connected Clients.

I can confirm that that socket is working because I am able to see the static connection string on 'ws.send' in the 'connection' block when I connect at ws://localhost:3000, as well as seeing mulitple clients logged out from the broadcast method if I connect with multiple clients.

Any help as to what I may be missing would be greatly appreciated,

```
var WebSocketServer = require('uws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 3000 }); // ws://localhost:3000

// Static test var
var test_message = {
    'test': 'Response',
    'test2': 'Response2'
};

// Broadcast to all.
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    console.log('IT IS GETTING INSIDE CLIENTS');
    console.log(client);

    // The data is coming in correctly
    console.log(data);
    client.send(data);
  });
};

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
   ws.on('message', function(message) {
     wss.broadcast(test_message);
     console.log('Received: ' + message);
   });

   // TODO This is static just to check that the connection is properly working
   ws.send('You successfully connected to the websocket.');
});
```

Comment: it seems to be working in my case. Can you share the client code ?

Comment: Right now I am just using a chrome extension to test the socket, I don't have a client written. The extension that I am using is called "Smart Websocket Client", not able to see the broadcast pushing the message to the response portion of this client. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code with `Smart Websocket Client`. Your code is fine. If you broadcast data having `string` only, then you can see the reply in UI, but for `javascript` `object`, the client doesn't display although you can see response as `Binary Frames (opcode = 2)` in `Chrome Developer Tools`.

The reason behind this behavior is that the `ws.send()` method support normal strings, typed arrays or blobs, but sending typed arrays and blobs will result in the frame(s) received by the client as binary frames (opcode = 2).

You can try `JSON.stringify` the `object`,

```
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
   ws.on('message', function(message) {
     wss.broadcast(JSON.stringify(test_message));
     console.log('Received: ' + message);
   });

   ws.send('You successfully connected to the websocket.');
});
```

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Appreciate the help a lot, makes sense why I could see the object in console log's but not within the broadcast in the UI.