# Firestore Real Time updates connection in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, websocket, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a NodeJS web app to receive Real Time updates from Firestore DB through Admin SDK.

This is the init code for the Firestore object. It's executed just once, when the app is deployed (on AWS Elastic Beanstalk):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./../key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

var db = admin.firestore();

FUNC.firestore = db;
```

Then I use this firestore object in a websocket comunication to send realtime updates to browser. The idea is to use the server as a proxy between browser and Firestore.

```
socket.on('open', function (client) {
    var query = FUNC.firestore.collection("notifications").doc(client.user.id.toString()).collection("global");
    query.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            client.send({ id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data(), type: change.type });
        });
    }, err => {
        console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    });
});

socket.on('close', function (client) {
    var unsub = FUNC.firestore.collection("notifications").doc(client.user.id.toString()).collection("global").onSnapshot(() => {
    });
    unsub();
});
```

It works well for a while, but after few hours the client stop receiving `onSnapshot()` updates, and after a while the server log the error: `Encountered error: Error: 10 ABORTED: The operation was aborted.`

What's wrong? Should I initialized firestore on each connection? Is there some lifecycle mistake?

Thank you

**EDIT (A very bad solution)**

<strike>I've tried to create a single firebase-admin app instance for each logged user and changed my code in this way</strike>

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./../key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

FUNC.getFirestore = function (user) {
  try {
    user.firebase = admin.app(user.id.toString());
    return user.firebase.firestore();
  } catch(e) {
    //ignore
  }

  var app = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  }, user.id.toString());

  user.firebase = app;

  return user.firebase.firestore();
}

FUNC.removeFirebase = function (user) {
  if (user.firebase) {
    user.firebase.delete();
  }
}
```

<strike>And then socket listeners:</strike>

```
    self.on('open', function (client) {
        var query = FUNC.getFirestore(client.user).collection("notifications").doc(client.user.id.toString()).collection("global");
        query.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.docChanges().reverse();
            querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                client.send({ id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data(), type: change.type });
            });
        }, err => {
            console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
        });
    });

    self.on('close', function (client) {
        var unsub = FUNC.getFirestore(client.user).collection("notifications").doc(client.user.id.toString()).collection("global").onSnapshot(() => {
        });
        unsub();
        FUNC.removeFirebase(client.user);
});
```

<strike>So when a client disconnect for a reason the server removes its firebase app, it works, but I've noticed a **huge** memory leak on server, I need some help</strike>

Comment: Please check in `google-cloud-firestore` documentation limits. Either you have reached the firebase connection time limit or the session operation limit. Detect this situation and re-establish the connection. Or better periodically test connection status.

Comment: I see, so according to you, is better to have a single firebase-admin instance and check connection timeouts, ore use multiple firebase-admin instances (one for each logged user)?

Comment: IDK, I don't know firebase, but standard for websockets is one datasource and broadcasting results for al users. Finally life will show what is possible to do ;)

Comment: And I think I know why you do not work. If one of the recipients closes the connection from the websocket, then you end up connecting to `firesotre` for everyone. Or I do not know myself anymore, you create a new connection for each client... Please check this, how to send broadcast message https://stackoverflow.com/q/41773965/1194525

Comment: No no, when a client disconnect I close only onSnapshot listener for that specific user collection, not the whole firebase connection, indeed for some hours it works well (tested with 20 users connected). Anyway I'm making more test so I could add more details to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

After many reaserch I've understand that this kind of approach is **wrong**. Of course, the old answer could be a workaround but is not the real solution of the problem, because Firestore was not designed to do something like: `Firestore <--(Admin SDK)--> Server <--(WebSocket)--> Client`.

In order to create the best comunication I have understand and applied Firestore Security Rules (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) together with Custom token generation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). So the correct flow is:

```
Client login request --> Server + Admin SDK generate custom auth token and return to client
```

Then, the real time comunication will be only between Client and Firestore itself, so: `Client + Custom Auth Token <--(Firebase JS SDK)--> Firestore DB`

As you can see, the server is not involved anymore in real-time comunication, but client receive updates directly from Firestore.

**OLD ANSWER**

Finally I can answer from myself. First of all the second solution I've tried is a very bad one, because each new app created through Admin SDK is stored in RAM, with 20/30 users the app reaches more then 1GB of RAM, absolutely unacceptable.

So the first implementation was the better solution, anyway I've wrong the register/unregister onSnapshot listener lifecycle. Each `onSnapshot()` call returns a different function, even if called on the same reference. So, instead of close the listener when socket close, I opened another one. This is how should be:

```
socket.on('open', function (client) {
    var query = FUNC.firestore.collection("notifications").doc(client.user.id.toString()).collection("global");
    client.user.firestoreUnsub = query.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            client.send({ id: change.doc.id, body: change.doc.data(), type: change.type });
        });
    }, err => {
        console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    });
});

socket.on('close', function (client) {
    client.user.firestoreUnsub();
});
```

After almost 48h, listeners still works without problems and no memory leaks occurs.

Comment: How did you manage to send a parameter within socket connection ? Can you also share your client side ?